# After changing hostname File Manager doesn't list "Computer"

Tags: nautilus, hostname

I successfully and permanently changed my hostname from bryan-OptiPlex-755 to just "bryan office". The hosts and hostname files are correct.
Before the change the file manager (Files/Nautilus 3.14.3) listed Computer for the root of the file system /.
After the change it lists it as Bryan Office.

How can I change that back to simply "Computer?"

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: did you tried right-clicking on the name and renaming it?

Comment: Yes - rename is  greyed out for me and su.
Also tried going back to the old computer name (the exact name is still visible in xauth list).